# Python 2.7 NameError : name 'hello' (my file) name is not defined

Tags: python

I am not sure if this question has been answered, but before you say yes please look at my problem more carefully. I am a beginner in python, though I have set my EVN and everything works good there. To make some advance stuffs, I need to create my file and I named it: hello.py
From command line I can navigate to the directory and then I tried to execute the hello.py. It contains the following code.

```
import sys

class Greeting:

    def main(argv):
        # My code here
        print ("Good day")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Greeting().main(sys.argv)
```

Here is the error I am getting

```
>>> hello.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
>>>
```

Could it be that file "hello.py" needs to be define some where, I don't really understand.

Comment: run it using `python hello.py`

Comment: You tried to run it from the Python REPL. You have to launch it from the command line of your OS. Btw, if you're a beginner, you should really use Python 3 rather than 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run a file using python {file_name}.py.

```
import sys

class Greeting:

    def main(argv):
        # My code here
        print ("Good day")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Greeting().main(sys.argv)
```

if your saved file name is hello.py
then use `python hello.py` in terminal.

Comment: All the answers provided are correct but you offers a good answer. I understand that the problem is from indentation.  I am running python from Anaconda Prompt. Though the error was misleading.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To run python files you must use `python hello.py`

To make the file executable on Linux or Mac you can also add

```
#!/bin/python
```

to the top of the file to run with just `hello.py`

Answer (score 0):

```
flag = True
print('hello I am Academia. Start typing your query after greeting to me. for Ending convo type bye')
while(flag == True):
 user_response = input()
 user_response = user_response.lower()
 if('user_response!= bye'):
   if(user_response == 'thaknyou' or user_response == 'thanks'):
     flag= False
     print('Academia: your welcome..')
   else:
     if(greet(user_response)!=None):
          print('Academia: '+ greet(user_response))
     else:
            sentence_tokens.append(user_response)
            word_tokens = word_tokens + nltk.word_tokenize(user_response)
            final_words =list(set(word_tokens))
            print('Academia: ', end = '')
            print(response(user_response))
            sentence_tokens.remove(user_response)
 else:
               flag = False 
               print('Academia: goodbye')
```

name error showing
name greeting is not defined

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).